# auto generate value into a column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to my SQL and I have some question.

For example, if I have a table

```
create table if not exists product(
         id int not null auto_increment,
         product_type_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         product_type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         primary key(id)
);
```

I want my product_type_id to automatically have the first three letters from the product_type column, a -,  and a number. For example, if I insert product_type is a grocery, is there a way that it can automatically insert gro-1 into product_type_id column?

Comment: Consider whether this is really what you want.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You don't want that to be main id, but you can generate MySQL view and use that to generate column where you will construct a new custom  identifier automatically.

Comment: id is still the main id, i forgot to edit primary key(id)

Comment: I do exactly what you want do, my custom id looks like: P-2/44, it combines 3 logic parts. Research MySQL view: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx And generate that column there. Then use that view table everywhere for viewing.

Comment: Where a number (1 in gro-1 in an example) is taken from?